# Using R in Jupyter Notebook without Anaconda

Tags: python, r, github

I use Python a lot, especially on Jupyter notebook. I have python version 3.9.13. I am trying to open an R notebook within Jupyter so that I can write R code as usual in a jupyter notebook just like I usually do with python. However, I don't have that option with jupyter notebook, I can only create a python file.

I tried installing the R kernel as per the instructions here:    https://irkernel.github.io/installation/. When I try this in R, I get the error: Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘IRkernel’.

I've had issues using python and R together before, it ended up messing up environments somehow but I'm not really sure how it works. How do I use R in jupyter notebook? Are my versions compatible with each other or do I have to use precise versions of R and python together? How does this work without Anaconda? Thanks.

Comment: You say, "I tried installing the R kernel  as per the instructions here: https://irkernel.github.io/installation/.", but you don't detail what and where or what step gives you that error. Is it the first one?  Do other R packages fail  to install or not? That stuff may or may not be important if the following helps you: [This old post looks like a similar issue](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/583). Read through and see if it helps. I think [this comment and the link therein may be key](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/583#issuecomment-461341774). Or maybe the one ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/583#issuecomment-671079096).